dl.wine.hq errors
so i've been having problems with Wine since i first installed it. i don't remember exactly how i installed it, but i tried deleting it, and while it is deleted, some packages(i think) are left of it that are stopping me from upgrading my ubuntu and its softwares. it's really messing with my head.
so i was getting all kinds of errors while using sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade, and then i got a notification that there's a new ubuntu version available (i'm using ubuntu 22.04 LTS jammy) and so i tried upgrading through command line with sudo do-release-upgrade and got the Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading. error.
i then tried this:
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
for i in *.list; do mv ${i} ${i}.disabled; done 
apt clean
apt autoclean 
sudo do-release-upgrade

and it did marvels for the most part, and i could update and upgrade successfully. but then when i tried do-release-upgrade i got errors related to Wine again. this is what i get when i run sudo do-get-release:
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [833 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,277 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,278 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'noble.tar.gz' against 'noble.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'noble.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done             
Ign https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Ign https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Ign https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Err https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
  Could not handshake: Error in the pull function. [IP: 146.75.118.217 443]    
Fetched 0 B in 6s (0 B/s)                                                      
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done

Checking for installed snaps

Calculating snap size requirements

Updating repository information           
Ign https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Ign https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Ign https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Err https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
  Could not handshake: Error in the pull function. [IP: 146.75.54.217 443]     
Fetched 0 B in 6s (0 B/s)                                                                  
Ign https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Ign https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Ign https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Err https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
  Could not handshake: Error in the pull function. [IP: 146.75.118.217 443]    
Fetched 0 B in 6s (0 B/s)                                                      
Ign https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Ign https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Ign https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Err https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
  Could not wait for server fd - select (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) [IP: 146.75.54.217 443]
Fetched 0 B in 6s (0 B/s)                                                      

Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done

can someone help me get rid of wine for good? any help is appreciated.

Let's be more specific here: Your problem is with upstream Wine sources and packages that are not tested for compatibility with your release of Ubuntu. Folks using Wine are recommended to use the tested, compatible packages in the Ubuntu repositories instead.

The basic theory of repair has two steps: 1) apt list wine* | grep installed to list the wine packages installed. Review the list and uninstall them. 2) Disable or delete the apt repository that those packages came from. Do not start a release-upgrade until ALL apt update and upgrade errors have been fixed.

I suspect that the Wine installer modified the /etc/apt/sources.list file directly. Take a look at it and (after making a copy somewhere) remove any entries that refer to winehq.
Also, if you have a file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources.disabled, you should change it back to being named ubuntu.sources. (I don't have a 22.04 system handy so I don't recall when they switched to it being a separate file.)
